# Is there a way to transform an imported component into an standalone component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular-standalone-components

I installed the next component: https://github.com/orahul1/angular-audio-player
BUt because im using angular 17 i began working with standalone components. Is there a way to use transform that component into a standalone one? or use it in some way?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, NavBarComponent, FooterComponent, HttpClientModule, AngMusicPlayerModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Patata Ceramica';
}
```

```
Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.(-992012)
```

Comment: Which component is giving you problems(which do you want to convert to standalone? could you provide a stackblitz if possible?

Comment: How about you read the README in the provided npm package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `AngMusicPlayerModule` module in the `imports` instead of the component itself.